# How to reverse a linked list at an assigned index?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public void reverse(int index) {
    if (first == null) {
        return;
    }
    int count = 0;
    Node current = first;
    Node previous = null;
    Node next;

    while (current != null && count < index && index> 0) {
        next = current.next;
        current.next = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
        count++;
    }
    first = previous;
}
```

Here is my code. So I want to reverse a linked list and stop the reverse process at index. For example, suppose I have {One Two Three Four Five}, and the index is 3. So the output will be {Three Two One Four Five}. But for my code, I was able to reverse the data before the given index, but for some reason, the output becomes {Three Two One}. How do I keep the rest of the data while reversing at the given index?

Answer (score 0):

From my post at [Issues with reversing objects in a LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269638/issues-with-reversing-objects-in-a-linkedlist)

If you pass index greater than the number of elements in the list, then it simply reverses the entire list.
If you pass 0 or 1, the list will be unaffected

```
public boolean reverseTillIndex(int index) {
    int count = 0;
    if (index == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    Node endCountNode = head;

    while (count++ < index && endCountNode != null) {
        endCountNode = endCountNode.next;
    }
    count = 0;

    // standard reverse a list code
    Node current = head;
    Node h2 = null;

    while (current != null && count++ < index) {
        head = current.next;
        current.next = h2;
        h2 = current;
        current = head;
    }

    head = h2;
    while (h2.next != null) {
        h2 = h2.next;
    }
    h2.next = endCountNode;
    return true;
}
```